# Advantage of existing Cryptosystems

Tags: cryptanalysis, perfect-secrecy

I have read about the concept of perfect secrecy and statistical distance. The perfect secrecy is impossible to be implemented on real world scenario. So the cryptosystems used at various websites will have certain advantage which will be negligible. Is there a list stating the advantage of various cryptosystems like AES,DES which are applied in real world scenarios. Which cryptosystem achieves the least advantage and what's the mathematical concept involved in it?

Comment: Perfect secrecy isn't impossible. It just requires a key as long as the message, and the key cannot be reused.

Comment: A crypto system doesn't have an advantage. An adversary breaking a system does.

Comment: Yes I was asking regarding the advantage for different crypotsystems that an adversary can gain.

Comment: You can look at the best known public cryptanalysis for that

Comment: We don't really have an upper bound for the advantage, since that would require proving P!=NP (and more)

Comment: All symmetric or asymmetric cryptosystem has their own disadvantage and advantage, as they have different modes of operation like in symmetric encryption(CBC, CFB,CTR etc.) , also key length.  so, if you have specific scenario or mode of encryption, we can try.

Answer (score 0):

I'll slightly expand on [this comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/86643/advantage-of-existing-cryptosystems#comment189985_86643). Basically to get the biggest (currently known) advantage of an adversary you'd find the best security analysis for the schemes used for the protocol that are practical for the usage scenario.

The inverse of the bit strength of each scheme should be the advantage that the adversary has. Note that we don't know if the the bit strength of the various primitives is optimal, nor do we know if the combination of the primitives in schemes may not result in a lower bit strength. It's just that the current analysis hasn't shown any better attack yet (and, no, just stating that we will find one in the future because science always progresses doesn't cut it).